# Micrometer gauge metric update value slowly?

Tags: httprequest, prometheus, vert.x, gauge, micrometer

I'm using micrometer gauge metric to monitor Http_max_response_time in Vertx service. (configure metric with Prometheus).

When testing, I send a request with timeout 3 seconds at **13:15:16** and the gauge metric return right value about Http_max_response_time (3s). But after that request, there is not any request with timeout 3 seconds send to server, the gauge metric still return Http_max_response_time  = 3 second until **13:17:51**, and then it updates new value Http_max_response_time to less than 3s. I think it need update more frequently.

My questions here:

1. How long the gauge metric update new value OR how long it keeps current value?
2. Which logic that the gauge metric Http_max_response_time execute? Does it just update a global value and return it when there is an observation?

If my question is not clear, please comment and I will show detail more.
Thank in advance,

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is your setup and who provides this "Http_max_response_time" gauge ? In vertx-micrometer-metrics module, there is no such gauge, see https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-micrometer-metrics/java/

Comment: Beside my question above, I can answer on this: as you suspect, Gauge metrics in micrometer will only provide value when observed. Unlike Counters or Summaries, they cannot track whatever happens between two observations. In vertx-micrometer-metrics we use a Timer metric for response time, which is a special kind of Summary.

Comment: Thanks @Joel, you are right, vertx-micrometer-metrics use a Timer metric for response time. Before I thought it is Gauge metric as informations showing on localhost:8080/metrics. **# TYPE vertx_http_server_responseTime_seconds_max gauge**. I changed DistributionStatisticConfig and this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**:

Vertx-micrometer-metrics use a **Timer** metric for response time, and using a TimeWindowMax to update highest value.

> Max for basic Timer implementations such as CumulativeTimer, StepTimer is a time window max (TimeWindowMax). It means that its value is the maximum value during a time window. If no new values are recorded for the time window length, the max will be reset to 0 as a new time window starts. Time window size will be the step size of the meter registry unless expiry in DistributionStatisticConfig is set to other value explicitly. The reason why a time window max is used is to capture max latency in a subsequent interval after heavy resource pressure triggers the latency and prevents metrics from being published.

So we can change default expiry configuration in **DistributionStatisticConfig** to smaller value as you want.

Here my code to change TimeWindowMax of metrics which contain responseTime to 2 seconds:

```
registry.config().meterFilter(
            new MeterFilter() {
                @Override
                public DistributionStatisticConfig configure(Meter.Id id, DistributionStatisticConfig config) {
                    if(id.getName().contains("responseTime")) {
                        return DistributionStatisticConfig.builder()
                                .expiry(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
                                .build()
                                .merge(config);
                    }
                    return config;
                }
            });
```

And It worked.